# Unable to use Bash's "-i" option from ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, linux, processbuilder, io-redirection

The goal of my program is to run an interactive command line executable from Java, so I can add input partway through when required. Basically redirecting input.

I couldn't find anything that worked online because the `-c` flag does not allow interactivity, but then I saw that the `-i` flag in the terminal allowed me to run commands with interactive input if I fed it a .sh file.

However, when I tried using this flag in java, it didn't work. I have separate input and output threads, so if I could get this to work it seems like it would be easy.

Relevant code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder()
                    .directory(new File(testDir))
                    .inheritIO()
                    .command("bash", "-i"
                    ,"executor.sh");

            proc = pb.start();
```

this is the error i get:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (1469): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

If there's  way I could get this -i option working, then I'd appreciate pointers to something else that would allow me to get interactive input working because nothing else that I've tried seems to solve this problem.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what `bash -i` does. It **doesn't** redirect input from the TTY; it just tells the shell to run in the same mode it would behave in by default if its stdin *was* a TTY (and it was run with no script name passed as argument).

Comment: ...so, `-i` turns on evaluation of `.bashrc`, and enables some other facilities meant for interactive rather than scripted use, but it doesn't accomplish the goal stated in the question.

Comment: (Similarly, where did you get the idea that "the `-c` flag doesn't allow interactivity"? You can test that that's wrong at the prompt: `bash -c 'read -p "Reading from the user" value; echo "Read value: $value"` is properly able to interact, when run at a shell where its stdin points to the TTY at startup time).

Comment: I think i understand that though I'm not really sure, but how can I redirect the input then? Redirecting the output is trivial but I still have no idea how to redirect the input after reading dozens of answers and documentation pages.

Comment: I'm showing that in my answer.

Comment: Ok now I see that the -c flag does allow interactivity, but it's blocked in my java program for whatever reason.

Comment: So, a good place to start (if `/dev/tty` doesn't work -- when you use my answer, does the `ERROR` log line trigger?) is by logging `ls -l /proc/self/fd` from your shell script, to get an idea of which file handles are open when ProcessBuilder spawns a child and where they're pointing at.

Comment: BTW -- how was the JVM itself invoked? If it was started from a systemd or launchd service... well, that would explain why it doesn't have a controlling TTY.

Comment: the program runs from netbeans.

Comment: If you run it with `java -jar yourprogram.jar` at a terminal manually, do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

`bash -i` is completely unrelated to ability to read from the TTY.

Rather, redirect *from* the TTY, after your script already started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec </dev/tty || { echo "ERROR: Unable to connect stdin to /dev/tty" >&2; exit 1; }
read -r -p "Fill out this prompt please: " value
echo "Read from TTY: $value"
```

The command `exec </dev/tty` replaces the script's stdin (FD 0) with a read handle on `/dev/tty`. If you wanted to do this just for a single command, rather than for the whole script, put `</dev/tty` on the end of that command.

Of course, this only works if your process is run in a context where it *has* a controlling terminal at all -- but if that weren't the case, you couldn't read from the user without getting *some* kind of handle on an I/O device regardless.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I realized that my input function was already sort of working, except it wasn't terminating correctly so maybe I should make a separate question about that if I can't figure it out.  dev/tty wasn't recognized, i guess because it's an IDE.

Comment: Your IDE's implementation details matter here. One *could* have an IDE start a terminal and attach programs to it, but whether that's feasible is a Netbeans question more than a bash one.